# How to join multiple tables in HQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

I Have this entity classes:

```
public class Work implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer workId;
private User userByCreateBy;
private User userByUpdateBy;
private Long studyId;
private String name;
private byte panelType;
private byte status;
private Date createDate;
private Date updateDate;
private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>(0);

public Work() {
}
```

}

```
private Integer taskId;
private User userByCompleteBy;
private User userByExecutedBy;
private Work work;
private byte type;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private byte status;
private Date updateDate;
private Forecast forecast;
private Set<ForecastOutput> forecastOutputs = new HashSet<ForecastOutput>(0);
private MonitorLottery monitorLottery;
private QprMonitorLotteryArea qprMonitorLotteryArea;
private Set<QprMonitorLotteryOutput> qprMonitorLotteryOutputs = new HashSet<QprMonitorLotteryOutput>(0);
private Set<ForecastCellafter740> forecastCellafter740s = new HashSet<ForecastCellafter740>(0);
private Set<QprMonitorLotteryResult> qprMonitorLotteryResults = new HashSet<QprMonitorLotteryResult>(0);
private Set<AnswerDataOutput> answerDataOutputs = new HashSet<AnswerDataOutput>(0);
private QprMonitorLottery qprMonitorLottery;
private AnswerDataCheck answerDataCheck;

public Task() {
}
```

}

public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

```
private Integer userId;
private String userName;
private String password;
private String name;
private String email;
private byte authority;
private Date lastLogin;
private Date passwordChangeDate;
private byte status;
private Integer createBy;
private Integer updateBy;
private Date createDate;
private Date updateDate;
private Set<MasterFile> masterFiles = new HashSet<MasterFile>(0);
private Set<Task> tasksForCompleteBy = new HashSet<Task>(0);
private Set<Work> worksForCreateBy = new HashSet<Work>(0);
private Set<Work> worksForUpdateBy = new HashSet<Work>(0);
private Set<Task> tasksForExecutedBy = new HashSet<Task>(0);

public User() {
}
```

}

I want to join this tables using hql and get the details of username,workname,task.type,task.status etc.. I have done this code

```
 StringBuilder dataQuery = new StringBuilder("select new com.web.main.view.WorkView("
        + "w.workId, "
        + "w.studyId, "
        + "w.name, "
        + "w.panelType, "
        + "t.type, "
        + "t.status, "
        + "u.user_name,"
        + "w.createDate, "
        + "w.updateDate, "
        + "t.startDate, "           
        + "t.endDate ) "
        + "from Work w  left join w.tasks t  left join w.user u where u.user_Id = w.create_by and w.status!=:status");
```

But it is given  the error

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: user of,

What will be the issue am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

There is no field named `user` on the `Work` entity. So you should replace `w.user` with `w.userByCreateBy` or `w.userByUpdateBy` (or rename entity field).

Answer (score 0):

In Work entity I dont see user field 
you have

```
private User userByCreateBy;
private User userByUpdateBy;

private User userByCompleteBy;
private User userByExecutedBy;
```

Problem is in this line

```
left join w.user u where u.user_Id = w.create_by
```

You need to have User List in Work to left join same like Task

Comment: How to correct it with user list.  This private User userByCreateBy is enough     for join right?

Comment: If you want left join you need a list same like Task else use direct join

Comment: I tried select count(*) from Work w  left join w.tasks t join w.user u where w.status!=:status but it results in error  HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: user

Comment: It should be   select count(*) from Work w left join w.tasks t join w.userByCreateBy u where w.status!=:status     you can use only variables which are defined in Entity user field is not defined